# Losing focus on selected item in ListView?

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I have a method that can remove an item from a list:

```
def listCleaner(self, *args):
    if self.the_mLv.adapter.selection:
        self.the_mLv.adapter.data.remove(itemSelected)
        self.the_mLv._trigger_reset_populate()
    else:
        pass
```

When I try to remove this item from another class. A class that handles
a popup to warn the user they are about to delete the item in the
list, it returns `NONE`:

```
class itemToDelete(Popup):            

    def yesToRemove(self):        
        with open(mgs.strip() + "mylist.txt", "r") as mLst:
            remove = [itemSelected]
            tempLst = [ ]
            for line in mLst:
                for iS in remove:
                    if iS in line:
                        line = line.replace(iS, ' ')
                        line = line.strip()
                tempLst.append(line)
            mLst.close()

        #Writing back the changes to "mylist.txt"
        with open(mgs.strip() + "mylist.txt", "w") as lstWb:
            for line in tempLst:
                lstWb.write(line)
            lstWb.close()

        #Delete item from observable list
        delFromLst = mgsApp()
        delFromLst.listCleaner()
        #print "Remove item from list"

        #Check filesize of "mylist.txt"
        mLfs = os.stat(mgs.strip() + "mylist.txt")
        mLActual = mLfs.st_size

        if mLActual > 1:
            pass
        else:        
            #Remove mylist.txt
            listDone = lstFinalRemove()
            listDone.open()
```

Above, the reference to the class `mgsApp` and
the method within, `listCleaner`, I can not remove
the item from the list.

Can this kind of action be performed? I'm sure it can.
If you can bring any suggestions to the table, It would be
highly appreciated.

I would not mind posting the full script of what I been working on,
of course it's 1300+ lines. What is the best way doing that?
Patebin? Please let me know.

Comment: If your code is more than 200 lines it is not appropriate that you share it, nobody will read it and it will not be used either since it is complicated to debug a lot of code, SO I recommend that you make an effort, yes, it is a bit more work, and you create a [mcve]. read [ask]

Comment: Your line: `delFromLst = mgsApp()` is creating a new instance of `msgApp`. If you want to access a running App, you can use `App.get_running_app()`

Comment: @John Anderson - Thank you my friend, you fixed a two month "spinning my wheels" problem. This has been killing me. I've been working on this project for 14 months. You finished it with that suggestion. Final code that works: `delFromLst = App.get_running_app()
        delFromLst.main_screen.listCleaner()`